# Lucene custom scoring / analyzer

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine

I`d like to do something like that:
When I add a document and some text is going with (e.g.) quotes it should mean that this text have to be exactly in the query.
Better with an examples -

text: green "blue apple" juice

query : blue apple        - result: hit.
query : blue apple juice  - result: hit.
query : apple blue        - result: none.
query : blue              - result: none.
query : blu appl          - result: none.

So, the words with quotes have to go exactly in this order as they are in doc

Can I do that with Lucene 8.* and how?
Maybe some another search engine can do that? (elasticsearc/solr/etc.)

Comment: The "classic" Lucene query parser supports querying on a phrase, which is a sequence of words surrounded by double-quotes. See the [syntax overview](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview). Or, you can do the same thing using the Lucene query API. I am not sure why you are referring to "custom scoring/analyzer" in the question's title. How does that relate to the rest of the question?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Otherwise, the question is too high-level and needs additional details, for clarification. If you have not already done so, you can take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @andrewjames thanks for your answer. It's not exactly what I need. I mean that if there is some phrase with quotes (quotes it's just example, it can be some another mark) in document's text, the query has to have exactly the same. For text: "very green apple" the query "green apple" shouldn`t find this document.

Comment: And I supposed that if it is possible to do, probably analyzer is responsible for that

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - and sorry for my misunderstanding. The Lucene `StandardAnalyzer` will remove punctuation marks, so you cannot use that. But you can use the [`WhitespaceAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html), which will keep punctuation when it generates the index tokens. It uses the `WhitespaceTokenizer` to do this. These classes are in Lucene's `analyzers-common` package.